# How to resolve the SVN:externals problem

Tags: svn, branch

I am using SVN for my project. I have two repositories called repo1 and repo2. In each repository, I have created a branch called branch1 in both repositories. For one of the modules in branch1 of repo2 called module1, an svn:external has been defined and is set to module1 of branch1 in Repo1.

But Now I created another branch called branch2 in repo1 and repo2 that is a copy of branch1 of both repos. Now my module1 in branch2 of repo2 still points to module1 of branch1 in repo1. But it should refer to module1 of branch2 in repo1.

Is there any way were we can change svn:externals automatically when we do a SVN copy or svn branch?

Comment: Could you add what you want to read by using `svn:externals`? Perhaps there is another solution possible with SVN. Why do have the two repositories the same structure, and it seems that repo2 should follow the structure of repo1.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible. I don't think there is a way for svn to know if you want the svn externals to refer to branch2 or branch1.

**Update**: This [discussion](http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2004-06/1345.shtml) looks useful.

Comment: In my opinion, it is a feature, not a bug. `svn:externals` should be used for stable references, so they should normally even point the a specific revision, and not to the head.

Answer (score 0):

No, what you need is not possible to be done by svn automatically. Creating a branch copies the entire folder in svn as well as all of its external references.

But you may write your own scripts to create the branch and update the externals.

Answer (score -1):

The definitive resource on [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.externals) shows some possibilities for "relative" links. But none of them can cross repository borders the way *you* want.

This leaves the following options:

- Put the related projects into the same repository and into the same branch directory and use relative svn:external links, or
- Use and/or hack a tool like `svncopy` which purpose is to deal with svn:externals. This tool is in the subversion source tree in `contrib/client-side/svncopy`.
- Or you can put branching/tagging into your build system.

None of these options is a nobrainer.